# Filtering elements based on accumulated sum of a field

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs5

Consider the data object like this

```
var data = [
    {name: 'abc', dis: 0},
    {name: 'bcd', dis: 30},
    {name: 'cde', dis: 70},
    {name: 'def', dis: 22},
    {name: 'efg', dis: 40},
    {name: 'fgh', dis: 29},
    {name: 'ghi', dis: 41},
    {name: 'hij', dis: 33}
];
```

I want to filter out object only when the accumulated distance is greater than or equal to 100. So required output would be

```
var finalData = [
    {name: 'abc', dis: 0},  //start point
    {name: 'cde', dis: 100}, // 0 + 30 + 70
    {name: 'ghi', dis: 132}, //22 + 40 + 29 + 41
    {name: 'hij', dis: 33}  // 33 as points ended
];
```

Offcourse I can easily do it via for-loop and push like this

```
var finalData = [];
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    sum += data[i].dis;
    if(i == 0 || sum >= 100) {
        finalData.push({name: data[i].name, dis: sum});
        sum = 0;
    }

}
```

but want do learn it in Rxjs style.

Comment: IMO, the for loop is going to be the cleanest way to code this.

Comment: The code is same, but using reduce its easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether specific RxJS functionalities could be of any help in that case. Did you mean Functional Programming?

You can use the `.reduce()` method with an accumulator and additional tests for the first and last elements.

As far as I can tell, your original code was only missing the test on the last element.

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'abc', dis: 0},
  {name: 'bcd', dis: 30},
  {name: 'cde', dis: 70},
  {name: 'def', dis: 22},
  {name: 'efg', dis: 40},
  {name: 'fgh', dis: 29},
  {name: 'ghi', dis: 41},
  {name: 'hij', dis: 33}
];

var sum = 0;

var finalData = data.reduce(function(prv, cur, i) {
  if((sum += cur.dis) >= 100 || !i || i == data.length - 1) {
    cur.dis = sum;
    sum = 0;
    prv.push(cur);
  }
  return prv;
}, []);

console.log(finalData);
```

If you want to avoid using a variable defined outside the scope of the `.reduce()` method, you can either use the optional `thisArg` parameter or an object instead of a simple array as the initial value.

I tend to prefer the second option which allows to explicitly initialize the accumulator from the beginning:

```js
var data = [
  {name: 'abc', dis: 0},
  {name: 'bcd', dis: 30},
  {name: 'cde', dis: 70},
  {name: 'def', dis: 22},
  {name: 'efg', dis: 40},
  {name: 'fgh', dis: 29},
  {name: 'ghi', dis: 41},
  {name: 'hij', dis: 33}
];

var finalData = data.reduce(function(prv, cur, i) {
  if((prv.sum += cur.dis) >= 100 || !i || i == data.length - 1) {
    cur.dis = prv.sum;
    prv.sum = 0;
    prv.res.push(cur);
  }
  return prv;
}, {sum: 0, res: []}).res;

console.log(finalData);
```

Comment: anyway to avoid dependency on global variable sum?